# Trigger in textbox inside CellEditingTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I have such a message

> Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' threw an
>   exception.

for this template

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <TextBox.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Time}" Value="39">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </TextBox.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

It started to appear after i added Trigger. What went wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use DataTrigger like below,it should be in Style,ControlTemplate and DataTemplate,So add the trigger to Style of Textbox

```
<TextBox.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Time}" Value="39">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </TextBox.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to fix it in this particular case?

Comment: This may work for you

<TextBox.Style>
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Time}" Value="39">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</TextBox.Style>